# How do I set a Postgres 9.6 password in Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to run a Ruby app locally, and trying to set up 'config/database.yl' file with a Postgres password.

When I installed Postgres 9.6 I was not prompted to set a password.

Any suggestions on how to set one up, or retrieve whatever the password is set to right now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your configuration look like?

Comment: why have you tagged your question with heroku?

Comment: I am using Ruby in Heroku.  I also re-installed Postgres on my computer and it still did not ask for, or display a password.

Comment: What does your question have to do with Heroku? Are you trying to run this application locally while connecting to your Heroku Postgres database?

Comment: In Heroku, I am trying to deploy a demo app with db, and instructions said to modify file config/database.yml with Postgres account and password and run it locally.